# Can we downgrade oracle database form 12cR2 to 12cR1

Tags: oracle-12c

I have upgraded the Oracle database to 12cR2, now I want to downgrade it to 12cR1.Is this possible?What are the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade both major releases and patchset releases, based on the original Oracle Database release from which the database was upgraded. Major release downgrades are supported back to Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.2) and subsequent 11.2 releases, and Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1.0.7). Patchset downgrades are supported back to Oracle Database release 11.2 patchsets, except release 11.2.0.1.

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/downgrade.htm#UPGRD00710) provides a summary of releases supported for downgrading.

Also, check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/downgrade.htm#UPGRD12554) for compatibility.